# How to solve this recurrence $T(n) = \log{n}*T(n/\log{n})+\sqrt{n}$

Tags: recurrence-relations

I tried substitution for $2^n$ or $2^{\log{n}}$ or even $2^{2^n}$ and it didn't work.

Thanks! :)

Comment: Side remark: you do realize $2^{\log n}=n$ (assuming base $2$), right? :)

Comment: Yeah haha figured it out later.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that this is an algorithmic complexity analysis, such that you have an appropriate base case for $n < 4$, and it's enough to get the asymptotic behavior.

We can then see at least informally that $T(n)$ is $\Theta(n)$ by bounding above and below:

**Lower bound:** The bottom layer of the recursion spends runs $\Theta(n)$ times and at least constant time is spent on each.

**Upper bound:** Imagine changing the divide-and-conquer such that the algorithm splits into only $2$ subcases at each level rather than $\log n$ subcases. This can only reasonably make it *slower*, since we already know that $T$ grows *at least* linearly. But even so we still would have
$$ T^*(n) = 2 T^*(n/2) + \sqrt{n} $$
and the Master Theorem then tells us that $T^*(n)$ is $\Theta(n)$. Since  $T^*(n)\ge T(n)$, we can conclude that $T(n)$ is $O(n)$ too.

Making this argument rigorous is left as an exercise for the reader :-)

Answer (score 0):

My solution is somewhat lengthy but straight forward. We have :-
$$T(n)=\log n*T\left(\frac{n}{\log n}\right)+\sqrt{n}$$$$\implies T(n)=\log n\log \left(\frac{n}{\log n}\right)* T\left(\frac{n}{(\log n)^2}\right)+\sqrt{n}+\sqrt{\frac{n}{\log n}}$$
so on......
$$\implies T(n)=\log n\log\left(\frac{n}{\log n}\right)\cdot\cdot\cdot\cdot \log\left(\frac{n}{(\log n)^{k-1}}\right)T(1)+\sqrt{n}+\sqrt{\frac{n}{\log n}}+....+\sqrt{\frac{n}{(\log n)^{k-1}}}$$
where $$n=(\log n)^k\implies k=\frac{\log n}{\log\log n}\tag{1.}$$
Now since $$\log \left(\frac{n}{(\log n)^a}\right)=\log n-a\log\log n=O(\log n)$$
So $$T(n)=(\log n)^{k-1}+O(\sqrt{n})$$
The rest is on you....